# serializing form not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use jquery/ajax to serialize a form inside a dialog box, but the form submits normal rather than via ajax, here's my javascript:

```
$('.modal-content').on('submit', "send_pm", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        headers: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (!data.success) {
                $.notify(data.error, "error");
            } else {
                $('#globalModal').dialog("close");
                $.notify(data.success, "success");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

My dialog box

```
<div class="modal" id="globalModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I am returning false on the jquery so it should submit normally, and here is my form:

```
<form action="<?php echo config::get('URL'); ?>messages/send_message" method="POST" id="send_pm">
    <div class="panel-default m-t-20">
        <div class="panel-body p-t-30">
            <div class="form-group" data-intro="<?php echo Tutorials::tutorial('message_compose_sender_to'); ?>" data-step="2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo system::escape($this->to); ?>" id="recipient" name="to">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" data-intro="<?php echo Tutorials::tutorial('message_compose_subject'); ?> " data-step="3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" value="<?php echo system::escape($this->subject); ?>" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" data-intro="<?php echo Tutorials::tutorial('message_compose_message_body'); ?> " data-step="4" data-position="top">
                <textarea id="compose-textarea" name="message" class="form-control" style="height: 300px">
                    <?php echo System::wysiwyg($this->
                            message); ?>
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right" data-intro="<?php echo Tutorials::tutorial('message_compose_discard_message'); ?>" data-step="1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple waves-effect waves-light"><span><?php echo System::translate("Send"); ?>
                            </span><i class="icon-mail-send"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You're missing the id selector on the `form` in your delegate handler: `$('.modal-content').on('submit', "#send_pm", function() {`

Comment: It still seems to submit normally even with the selector ;(

Comment: Is the AJAX request actually being sent? The first thing to check is that the event is being executed at all. Does the `.modal-content` element exist in the page when you attach the event?

Comment: .modal content is in the header.php file, and the form is in another file create.php, and when I click the link in the header it opens the create.php in the modal code above in the ehader

Comment: use event.preventDefault() first to stop submitting as normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, .modal-content is a **div** & send_pm  should be the name of form which is not inside .modal-content div.

so use **$(document).on** in place of **$('.modal-content').on**. 
You could use a suitable selector in place of document.

Also, as others have pointed in comments use #send_pm

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still struggling with this issue then you may try this solution. It worked for me.

```
$(document).on('click','.save-item', function(){
    var data = $('#saveItemModal .form-control').serializeArray();
});
```